# Set hourly limit on DateTimeField Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Models.py:

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I set hard limit for setting end_date?

So if the user wants to set anything over **5hours** from start system won't let him do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the database level using [constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/)

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CheckConstraint, Q, F

class Event(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end = models.DatetimeField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(end__lte=F('start') + timedelta(hours=5)), 
                name='check_end_datetime',
            ),
        ]
```

The run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` to alter the database.

Comment: what version of django are you using. This allows me to set time greater than 5 hours on django 3.1

Comment: Sorry, I missed to say, you have to run makemigrations and migrate to put the constraint in effect. I have edited my answer